# How to add text files in Clion

Tags: c++, clion

I am having trouble figuring out how to add text files in Clion. I tried to look in settings but I haven't been able to find where I can do it. Someone please help!

Answer (score 0):

To add a new file right-click on the directory where you want to add the file. Select `New` and `File`.

If you have an existing file somewhere in the project folder (for example if you copied it there) that doesn't show, then right-click on the project (or the folder where the file is located) and select `Reload from Disk`.